# Reloj de ajedrez/ Android Studio / Estudiante

Tags: java

Les comparto mi proyecto, cree dos contadores (CounterDown) que funcionan de manera muy básica. mi pregunta es : 1 -Cómo creo una condición de manera que al presionar un botón empiece la cuenta regresiva en el otro?
2- opte por reescribir el mismo código  tanto para el reloj 1 como para el reloj 2 , ya que de esta manera sería más fácil realizar cambios a cualquiera de estos, eso es correcto? (la pagina no me permite poner todo el código completo)
gracias por su tiempo!

```
 cuentaRegresivabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
     @Override                                                      
     public void onClick(View view) {                               
         inicioPausa();                                             

     }                                                              
 });                                                                
  public void inicioPausa() {   
      if (Inicio) {             
          stopTimer();          

      } else {                  
          startTimer();         

      }                        
  }                   

public void startTimer() {                                                                          

    cuentaRegresiva = new CountDownTimer(tiempoIzquierdaMilliSegundos, 1000) {                      
        @Override                                                                                   
        public void onTick(long l) {                                                                
            tiempoIzquierdaMilliSegundos = l;                                                       

            actualizarTimer();                                                                      

        }                                                                                           

        @Override                                                                                   
        public void onFinish() {                                                                    

        }                                                                                           
    }.start();                                                                                      

    cuentaRegresivabtn.setText("Pausa");                                                            
    Inicio = true;                                                                                  

}                  

public void stopTimer() {                  
    cuentaRegresiva.cancel();              


    cuentaRegresivabtn.setText("Pausa");   
    Inicio = false;                        

}              
public void actualizarTimer() {                                         

    int minutos = (int) tiempoIzquierdaMilliSegundos / 60000;           
    int segundos = (int) tiempoIzquierdaMilliSegundos % 60000 / 1000;   

    String tiempoIzq;                                                   

    tiempoIzq = "" + minutos;                                           
    tiempoIzq += ":";                                                   
    if (segundos < 10) tiempoIzq += "0";                                
    tiempoIzq += segundos;                                              

    cuentaRegresivatxt.setText(tiempoIzq);                              

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> opte por reescribir el mismo codigo tanto para el reloj 1 como para el
>   reloj 2 , ya que de esta manera seria mas facil realizar cambios a
>   cualquiera de estos, eso es correcto ?

Los relojes deberían ser iguales, por lo tanto solo sería necesario programar una sola clase `RelojJugadorDeAjedrez` y utilizar dos instancias del mismo para tomar los tiempos individuales de cada jugador.

Este reloj debe tener un método para activarlo y otro para pausarlo.

> Cómo creo una condición de manera que al presionar un botón empiece la
>   cuenta regresiva en el otro?

En la clase de la aplicación que convenientemente voy a llamar `RelojDeAjedrez` (la que tiene el main(String args[]) por ejemplo):

1. Crear las dos instancias de `RelojJugadorDeAjedrez' que vienen a ser los relojes individuales para cada jugador.
2. Definir un atributo para indicar a que jugador le toca jugar (indica cual de los dos relojes es que estaría en 'foco'). Y poner uno de los relojes en foco, seteando este atributo.
3. Definir un método que hace de botón de pausa. Cuando se apreta el botón de pausa llamando a este método, se detiene el reloj individual que está en foco, se cambia el foco al otro reloj individual, y se lo activa.

Comment: muchas gracias juan lo intentare de la manera que me propones!!

Comment: estuve trabajando a base de tu respuesta , te importaría ayudarme?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y debajo de la original agrega el código relevante con el que necesitas ayuda.